# Aligning Geom_points ggrepel labels with the secondary axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

My geom_points ggrepel labels not aligning with the secondary axis.It is picking up numbers of the primary axis. How do I change it?

```
BHAGWANPUR <- structure(list(STATE = c("UTTARAKHAND", "UTTARAKHAND", "UTTARAKHAND"
), DISTRICT = c("HARDWAR", "HARDWAR", "HARDWAR"), AC = c("BHAGWANPUR", 
                                                         "BHAGWANPUR", "BHAGWANPUR"), PARTY = c("INC", "BJP", "BSP"), 
VOTES = c(44882L, 42369L, 4069L), DELTA_VOTES = c(14835L, 
                                                  31719L, -32759L), VOTE_PERCENTAGE = c(48.2, 45.5, 4.4), SWING = c(9.9, 
                                                                                                                    31.9, -42.5), X.CHANGE = c(49.4, 297.8, -89), BASE_SHARE = c(38.2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 13.6, 4.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
BHAGWANPUR <- BHAGWANPUR %>% mutate(mpg_type=ifelse(BHAGWANPUR$SWING>0,"ABOVE","BELOW"))
BHAGWANPUR$PARTY <- factor(BHAGWANPUR$PARTY,levels=BHAGWANPUR$PARTY)
BHAGWANPUR
draw <- ggplot(BHAGWANPUR, aes(x=PARTY, y=DELTA_VOTES, label=DELTA_VOTES)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width=.5,aes(fill=PARTY))+geom_text(aes(label=DELTA_VOTES,vjust="top"),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00BFFF","#F98C1F","#22409A"))+labs(subtitle="2012 to 2017", 
                                                                  title= "Bhagwanpur,Uttarakhand") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

draw <- draw+geom_point(colour = c("#00BFFF","#F98C1F","#22409A"),data = BHAGWANPUR, aes(x=PARTY, y=(BASE_SHARE * 1000),group = 1))+geom_label_repel(
  aes(PARTY, BASE_SHARE, label = BASE_SHARE),
  fontface = 'bold', color = 'black',
  box.padding = unit(0.35, "lines"),
  point.padding = unit(0.5, "lines"),
  segment.color = 'grey50'
) +
  geom_line(data = BHAGWANPUR, aes(x=PARTY, y=BASE_SHARE * 1000,group = 1), stat="identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Votes", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./2000, name = "Base Share",labels =  function(x) paste0(x, "%"))) 
draw
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same missing with previous question. Use `1000 * BASE_SHARE` was missed on `geom_label_repel`

```
draw <- ggplot(BHAGWANPUR, aes(x=PARTY, y=DELTA_VOTES, label=DELTA_VOTES)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width=.5,aes(fill=PARTY))+geom_text(aes(label=DELTA_VOTES,vjust="top"),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00BFFF","#F98C1F","#22409A"))+labs(subtitle="2012 to 2017", 
                                                                  title= "Bhagwanpur,Uttarakhand") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

draw <- draw+geom_point(colour = c("#00BFFF","#F98C1F","#22409A"),data = BHAGWANPUR, aes(x=PARTY, y=(BASE_SHARE * 1000),group = 1))+geom_label_repel(
  aes(PARTY, BASE_SHARE * 1000, label = BASE_SHARE),
  fontface = 'bold', color = 'black',
  box.padding = unit(0.35, "lines"),
  point.padding = unit(0.5, "lines"),
  segment.color = 'grey50'
) +
  geom_line(data = BHAGWANPUR, aes(x=PARTY, y=BASE_SHARE * 1000,group = 1), stat="identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Votes", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./2000, name = "Base Share",labels =  function(x) paste0(x, "%"))) 
draw
```

[image]